# What's the correct way to unit test event handlers with Mocha?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a function that accepts an event handler to process messages as they are received and I want to write a unit test for it using Mocha.

```
chat.setupBroadcastChannel = async (a, b, callback) => {
        // do something
        return await otherFunction(..)
    }
chat.sendBroadcastMessage= async (a, b) => {
        // do something
        return await sendMessage(..)
    }
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('should setup a broadcast channel and send and receive a broadcast message', () => {
        const testMessage = 'Hello!'
        let expectedMessage = '{d"sender":"self","message":"Hello!"}'
        let receivedMessage
        return chat.setupBroadcastChannel(broadcastTopic, false, (topic, partition, message) => {
                receivedMessage = message.value.toString()
                console.log('Test: Received a broadcast message', receivedMessage)
                console.log(receivedMessage, expectedMessage)
                assert.equal(receivedMessage, expectedMessage)
            })
            .then(async () => {
                await chat.sendBroadcastMessage('self', testMessage)
            })
    })
```

The test does not work when `receivedMessage` does not match `expectedMessage`. It looks like the failed assertion is being picked up by Kafka (the messaging layer I am using) instead of Mocha

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2021-05-22T14:58:14.247Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Runner] Error when calling
 eachMessage","topic":"broadcast","partition":0,"offset":"138","stack":"AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]:
 '{\"sender\":\"self\",\"message\":\"Hello!\"}' == '{d\"sender\":\"self\",\"message\":\"Hello!\"}'\n
 at D:\\path\\test\\chat.js:21:20\n    at Runner.eachMessage (D:\\path\\backend\\kafka.js:44:17)\n
 at Runner.processEachMessage (D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:151:20)\n 
 at onBatch (D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:287:20)\n 
 at D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:339:21\n  
 at invoke (D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\utils\\concurrency.js:38:5)\n 
 at push (D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\utils\\concurrency.js:51:7)\n 
 at D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\utils\\concurrency.js:60:53\n 
 at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n  
 at D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\utils\\concurrency.js:60:20\n 
 at D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:329:11\n 
 at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n
 at D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:328:17\n 
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\n 
 at async Promise.all (index 0)\n  
 at async Runner.fetch (D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:354:5)\n 
 at async D:\\path\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\runner.js:383:9",
 "error":{"generatedMessage":true,"code":"ERR_ASSERTION",
 "actual":"{\"sender\":\"self\",\"message\":\"Hello!\"}",
 "expected":"{d\"sender\":\"self\",\"message\":\"Hello!\"}","operator":"=="}}
```

What's the correct way to setup this test?